# Trying to increase disk with GPT for SQL Server data, do we need to configure anything to SQL Server Application

Tags: sql-server-2008, disk-space, azure-vm

I am not a DBA, but SQL Developer.

Our company has a Azure VM that has a very active SQL Server 2008.

Currently, a disk drive (H:\ drive) that holds SQL data is getting full (up to 2 TB, possibly due to all log files we never trimmed).

Also, partition style for H:\ drive is MBR, so there is a limitation with this partition in the OS.

[image]

Our IT is trying to extend the disk up to (4 TB) using GPT.

This is IT's plan:

•       Leave H: (PID 1) untouched.

•       Create VM snapshot as a backup.

•   Format an **unused 4TB existing drive for extensibility (GPT)**

As a SQL Developer, I know little bit about SQL Server Admin part, and I am curious whether there
should be any type of configuration we have to do to SQL Server Mgmt Studio (SSMS) application itself or other app. in Windows that configures SSMS to make sure data carries to extension using GPT without any disruption to the data.

I am trying to make sure IT's operation goes smoothly without losing any data or performance in the future, and would like to get some feedback from the community.

**This is updated content** (after I got some feedback):
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*Leave H: (PID 1) untouched.*" and "*Format an unused 4TB existing drive for extensibility (GPT)*". What's your game plan to move the database to the new bigger drive?

Comment: @J.D. Thank you for your feedback. I am not sure. What is general procedure on this case?

Comment: Np, just wanted to make sure I didn't misunderstand. The steps at a high level usually involve updating the database file paths meta-data on the server, stopping the SQL Server service, moving the files to the new drive, and starting the SQL Server service back up. If I get a chance I'll write up an answer with details.

Comment: Do you know if the system databases (`master`, `model`, `msdb`, and `tempdb`) files are stored on the `H:` drive too? If so, do they also need to be moved to the new drive or is it ok by you guys to leave them on the old drive?

Comment: @J.D. That would be great. Our team is still learning this new task, so if you can refer to  links or provide on the bottom as answer, that would be superb! Regards to your questions about system databases, I am not sure the best way. I guess I will follow the most standard/safer way.

Comment: @J.D. I would like to follow up regards to how to find whether system databases are stored in H: drive and instruction regards to moving to the new drive. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I haven't had a chance to write up a formal answer yet. But regarding the locations of the system database files, you can run the following query to get that: `SELECT name AS FileLogicalName, physical_name AS FileLocation
FROM sys.master_files WHERE database_id <= 4`

Comment: @J.D. I ran the query you indicated, and added an image on the original content. It appears that they are all in C:\ drive.. I am not sure what H:\ contains..

Comment: Cool, thanks for the update. Those are just the system databases used by the SQL Server instance to function properly. The user created databases are probably what's on your `H:` drive. You can confirm this with the same query but changing the `WHERE` clause to the following: `SELECT name AS FileLogicalName, physical_name AS FileLocation FROM sys.master_files WHERE database_id > 4`. (`database_id`s #1 through #4 are the system databases, everything greater than 4 are the user created databases).

Comment: @J.D. Thank you. I just ran the query and posted the new screenshot. So, what is implication if we are extending disk to a drive (let's day I:\ drive). Change from H --> I for example? Do we just change the configuration like here? https://sqlandme.com/2013/03/18/sql-server-changing-default-database-location-for-server/   I updated the content more.